# List of Unicode characters that should be filtered in output?

Tags: unicode, escaping, jsonp, data-quality

Recently I hit a bug due to data quality with browser support, and I am looking for a safe rule for applying string escape without double size unless required.

A UTF-8 byte sequence "E2-80-A8" (U+2028, LINE SEPARATOR), a perfectly valid character in a Unicode database. However, that sequence represents a line-separator (Yes, other then "0A").

And badly, many browser (including Chrome, Firefox, and Safari; I didn't test others), failed to process a JSONP callback which has a string that contains that Unicode character. The JSONP was included by a non-Unicode HTML which I did not have any control.

The browsers simply reported INVALID CODE/syntax error on such JavaScript which looks valid from debug tools and all text editors. What I guess is that it may try to convert "E2-80-A8" to BIG-5 and broke JS syntax.

The above is only an example of how Unicode can break your system unexpected. As far as I know, some hacker can use RTL and other control characters for their good. And there are many "quotes", "spaces", "symbols" and "controls" in Unicode specification.

QUESTION:

Is there a list of Unicode characters for every programmer to know about hidden features (and bugs) which we might not want them effective in our application. (e.g. Windows disable RTL in filename).

EDIT:

I am not asking for JSON nor JavaScript. I am asking for general best practice of Unicode handing in all programs.

Comment: Since JSON is a generic serialisation format for Unicode, **nothing** must be filtered or you break interop. When browsers misinterpret JSON, whose encoding clearly is UTF-8, as a different encoding, the fault lies with the browsers; and *they* should be fixed. Gimping JSON is not the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a database of character properties and a report describing it, the [UNICODE CHARACTER DATABASE](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Properties), that gives a good idea of how browsers "should" treat a code point.  I love that word, "should".  Safest is going to be a whitelist, you could probably go with L|M|N|S, Letter or Mark or Number or Symbol.

Have a look at the [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) for a library

Answer (score 9):

It breaks javascript because strings cannot have newlines in them:

```
var myString = "

";

//SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Now, the UTF-8 sequence `"E2-80-A8"` decodes to unicode code point [`U+2028`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm), which is treated similar to newline in javascript:

```
 var myString = " ";

//Syntax Error
```

It is however, safe to write

```
var myString = "\u2028";
//you can now log myString in console and get real representation of this character
```

which is what properly encoded JSON will have. I'd look into properly encoding JSON instead of keeping a blacklist of unsafe characters. (which are U+2028 and U+2029 AFAIK).

In PHP:

```
echo json_encode( chr(0xe2). chr(0x80).chr(0xA8 ) );
//"\u2028"
```

Comment: JSON is only an example. There are XML encode, HTML text, HTML attribute, SQL, URI encoding, filename, email address, domain name...etc. In the above example, it is ALREADY using encoding method provided from framework; and which obviously has a bug.

Using of the API, did not ensure the character escape always correct and you might have to DIY when it broke.

Comment: More specificity, the JSONP was generated by Spring MVC API.

Comment: @DennisCheung JSONP is executed as javascript code while those others are just data, I don't see how they have anything to do with this. The problem you described only applies in JSONP.

Comment: It is a curious hole that U+2028/2029 are valid in JSON despite being invalid raw in JavaScript (and hence JSONP). A good JSON encoder should escape them for compatibility, but very few actually do.

Comment: That's why I ask not for JS, but for Unicode. I bet there are dozen of them should be handled by whom write those "escape/encode" API for all places

Comment: Javascript CAN have newlines in script: `var s="\n";` The issue you are mentioning is only a syntactic issue.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the Unicode charts. There's a list of non-printing characters. These are the ones that'd be potential troublemakers. Your friend U+2028 has a bunch of friends: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf And it's not just in the 2000 range.

You could either nuke them all, or separate them into different categories (the SEP chars like U+2028 becoming \n or escaped properly), etc.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

A-Z, a-z and 0-9 are generally safe. Outside those 62 characters, you will run to problems with some system. There's no other answer anyone can give you.

For example, you mention domain names. The only way to handle Unicode domain names is to follow RFC 3454 and RFCs 5890-5893, and process the data that way and only that way. Filenames on most Unix filesystems are arbitrary strings of bytes that don't include / or \0. Functionally treating a filename on Unix as a Unicode string without breaking anything is a question in itself. Note that Windows filenames are not A-Z safe; stuff like NUL and PRN are reserved names. Each domain is going to its own little issues and quirks, and no simple summary is going to suffice for everywhere.

Comment: It does n't make sense to me. If we could use only A-Z0-9, then what the UTF-8 for? It sound like day back to 7-bit BBS network and you have to Base64 everything. Unicode has too many designed feature we should learn and understand rather then ignore them.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use Unicode. I'm saying that you asked about domain name system; you need to look at those RFCs 3454 and 5890-5893. You asked about filenames; POSIX file names are an arbitrary string of bytes that do not contain \0 or \x2F. Windows filenames are case-insensitive UTF-16 and need excluding of a set of ASCII reserved names. The formal answers to what can go in those have no similarity.

Comment: Windows filename is a good example.  RTL is valid in filename specification (there was a virus use it), but it fact it should be blocked.  You cannot read that from the specification / RFC. Even who wrote the RFC need know Unicode before he can put those dangerous character to exclude list.

Comment: RTL must be valid in filenames to support Arabic and Hebrew. If you're talking about the RLO character, RFC 3454 does mention RLO. RLO is not a "dangerous" character in the arbitrary case; it can cause reordering of text in some circumstances that can be confusing. You don't want to filter it from arbitrary text, and in most cases, even in filenames, blocking it is problematic; you need to accept the filenames that are on the disk. And that's just one small domain; you want to know everything.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/ is a list of security considerations in Unicode. As you can see, it's a lot more complex then a list of characters, and depends hugely on your problem set.

Comment: @prosfilase you have the best answer